# Android: ArrayList getting nullpointer on second call

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So I'm working on an android app and currently having an issue with some code. It's quite simple actually... I fill an arraylist, also check if it gets filled (it does) and then request that arraylist later on. But somehow when I request the arraylist later on it's empty and I'm not making a new instance or anything... Or I'm just plain missing it.

So here's the code where it's going wrong...

```
package net.serellyn.c2m.cal2movement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TaskListener{

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private TaskListener listener;
    private Exercises exercises;

    //...

    private ArrayList<String> exerciseArrayList;

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setLayout();

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PreferenceValues", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        listener = this;
        exercises = new Exercises();
        new sc_getExercises(listener).execute("http://www.serellyn.net/c2e/app_backend/exercises.php");

    }

    @Override
    public void taskComplete(ArrayList e) {
        exercises.setExercises(e);
        for(Exercise a : exercises.getExercises()) {
            Log.i("DebugInfo", a.getExercise());
        }
        setLayout();
    }

    private void setLayout() {
        Typeface tf_dinBlack = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DIN_Black.ttf");
        Typeface tf_dinMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DIN_Medium.ttf");
        Typeface tf_dinLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DIN_Light.ttf");

        tv_appName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_appName);
        tv_appTagline = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_appTagline);
        tv_hourNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_hoursNumber);
        tv_hourText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_hoursText);
        tv_minutesNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_minutesNumber);
        tv_minutesText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_minutesText);
        tv_yourActivity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_yourActivity);
        s_activities = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s_activities);

        tv_appName.setTypeface(tf_dinBlack);
        tv_appTagline.setTypeface(tf_dinMedium);
        tv_hourNumber.setTypeface(tf_dinLight);
        tv_hourText.setTypeface(tf_dinLight);
        tv_minutesNumber.setTypeface(tf_dinLight);
        tv_minutesText.setTypeface(tf_dinLight);
        tv_yourActivity.setTypeface(tf_dinLight);

        setActivityValues();
    }

    private void setActivityValues() {
        for(Exercise a : exercises.getExercises()) {
            Log.i("DebugInfo", a.getExercise());
        }
    }
}
```

sc_getExercises is an AsyncTask which works as expected, and fills the 'exercises' array in 'TaskComplete' function. I loop the 'exercises'array to see if it's filled, and it is filled as it should be.

However, when I do the same in the 'setActivityValues' later on, I get a nullpointerexception.

So that's kinda... weird in my eyes. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the exercises class.

```
package net.serellyn.c2m.cal2movement;

import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Exercises {

        private ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;

        public Exercises(){
            exercises = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
        }

        public ArrayList<Exercise> getExercises() {
            return exercises;
        }
        public void setExercises(ArrayList<Exercise> exercises) {
            this.exercises = exercises;
        }    
    }
```

I hope someone can spot the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Please provide a complete stack trace. (2) Please provide only the part of code relevant to the problem, minimize your code and remove anything that is not connected to the problem itself.

Comment: wherer you initializing exerciseArrayList ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess and unclear question/code... I was about to rewrite the whole question until I found the thing causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is your method:

```
private void setActivityValues() {
    for(Exercise a : exercises.getExercises()) {
        Log.i("DebugInfo", a.getExercise());
    }
}
```

Either `exercises` is `null` (it is initialized in `onCreate`), or `exercises` in your Exercises class instance is null (gets a value at `taskComplete`, which invokes `setExercises`), or one of the exercises in the loop is `null`, or the `getExercise` has a `NullPointerException` bug.

Comment: How could I approach this the best way to figure out what's the exact problem? I've also tried both Log.i("DebugInfo", String.valueOf(exercises.getExercises().size())); and Log.i("DebugInfo", exercises.toString()); but they get a nullPointer as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found the issue, most dumb issue ever.

Comment: If my answer helped you, you might consider accepting it. If not, then please, answer your own question.

Answer (score -2):

It says nullPointerException, check your json parser it fufills your list properly or not.

Comment: It works, at this part: @Override
    public void taskComplete(ArrayList e) {
        exercises.setExercises(e);
        for(Exercise a : exercises.getExercises()) {
            Log.i("DebugInfo", a.getExercise());
        }
        setLayout();
    }    but later on the arraylist is just empty again.